# additive structure in a small multiplicative group of a finite field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime. Given a positive integer $n$, does there exist a 
$\beta$ in an extension of $F_p$ such that

1) If $F_p[\beta] = F_{p^N}$, then $N > n^n$; ( $\beta$ lies in a high extension)

2) The order of $\beta$ is at most $2^{poly(n)}$; ( $\beta$ has small order)

3) $\beta F_p + \beta^n F_p + \beta^{n^2} F_p + ... + \beta^{n^n} F_p 
\subseteq < \beta > $; (the subgroup generated by $\beta$ contains
a linear space )

Thanks,

Qi

Answer (score 3):

Probably not, assuming $p$ is fixed and $n$ is large enough. 
Have a look at section 5 in my paper A49 in: http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/vol7.html (for some reason the journal doesn't allow direct links to papers although is free access).

In the notation there, let $R(x)=x^{n-1}+1$. Note that, as a
consequence of your hypothesis 3), $\beta^{n-1}+1 \in <\beta>$, which 
implies that the order of $\beta^{n-1}+1$ is at most that of $\beta$.
This will give an upper bound for $N$ in terms of $n$, using your 
hypothesis 2). I haven't done the
calculation, so I don't know if this upper bound contradicts your hypothesis 1). Note
that the bounds that I get are probably much weaker than the truth, see e.g.,
the conjecture of Poonen's discussed in the paper.